# Swift 1.2 Add Parameters to URL not working. worked perfect earlier

Tags: swift, url, nsstring

I have updated my XCode to 6.3.2 and I am adding parameters to URL but "+" operator is not working and give me and error like below

This is my URL in which I added `strEmail` (NSString object) as parameter.

```
var urlstring = "http://example.com/api/api.php?action=getReceivedMessages&ReceiverEmail=" + strEmail
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
"Binary Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'NSString' "
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use string interpolation

```
var urlstring = "http://example.com/api/api.php?action=getReceivedMessages&ReceiverEmail=\(strEmail)"
```

or cast strEmail as String

```
var urlstring  = "http://example.com/api/api.php?action=getReceivedMessages&ReceiverEmail=" + (strEmail as String)
```

Answer (score 1):

From Swift 1.2, Implicit conversion from `NSString` to `String` has been removed:

From [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW3):

> The implicit conversions from bridged Objective-C classes (NSString/NSArray/NSDictionary) to their corresponding Swift value types (String/Array/Dictionary) have been removed, making the Swift type system simpler and more predictable.

You have to explicitly convert it to `String` with `as`:

```
"...iverEmail=" + (strEmail as String)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `NSString` to `String` type. There are different ways of doing that, see below:

```
var urlstring = "http://example.com/api/api.php?action=getReceivedMessages&ReceiverEmail=" + String(strEmail)
```

or

```
var urlstring = "http://example.com/api/api.php?action=getReceivedMessages&ReceiverEmail="
+ (strEmail as String)
```

or

```
var urlstring = "http://example.com/api/api.php?action=getReceivedMessages&ReceiverEmail=\(strEmail)"
```